# Array.map breaking the app in custom Material dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-material

I implemented an Angular Material custom `<mat-select>` to use an `<input>` for searching.

This works perfectly fine if I pass `options` as Array<CustomType, where CustomType has at least **value** and **label** properties. The problem arrives if, for example, instead of passing that `options`, I transformed it with the simplest `map` function as you can see in this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bugged-searchable-select?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

The problem can be observed here:

```
  myConst = [
    { label: 'ASDF', value: 'asdf', zzz: 'zzz1' },
    { label: 'QWERTY', value: 'qwerty', zzz: 'zzz2' },
    { label: 'ASDF 2', value: 'asdf2', zzz: 'zzz3' },
  ];

  /** This works perfectly */
  correct() {
    return this.myConst;
  }

  /** This makes the app crash */
  incorrect() {
    return this.myConst.map((x) => (
      { label: x.label, value: x.value }
    ));
  }
```

Edit:

```
/** This works too. But I cannot implement this sometimes */
correct2 = this.myConst.map(x =>
  ({label: x.label, value: x.value})
);

/** And this crash too */
get incorrect2() {
  return this.myConst.map(x =>
    ({label: x.label, value: x.value})
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** The fix I thought, was not fixing it at all, because, now the app doesn't crash, the searching on typing ability is gone :c

**Edit 2:** I ended up fixing it by, instead of using a `search()` function that gets called on typing, I made `filteredValues` a `get` with the same functionality!

---

I fixed it by adding ngFor trackby Angular native function

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let filter of filteredValues; trackBy: trackByFn" [value]="filter.value">
...
</mat-option>

trackByFn(idx: number, item: LabelValue) {
  return item.label;
}
```